# Fetching a segment of the URL in the address bar

Tags: c#, asp.net

This is what I tried:

```
string myURL= "http://mysite.com/articles/healthrelated";
String idStr = myURL.Substring(myURL.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

I need to fetch "healthrelated" ie the text after the last slash in the URL. Now the problem is that my URL can also be like :

```
"http://mysite.com/articles/healthrelated/"
```

ie "a Slash" at the end of that text too. Now the last slash becomes the one AFTER "healthrelated" and so the result I get using

```
String idStr = myURL.Substring(myURL.LastIndexOf('/') + 1);
```

is empty string..

what should my code be like so I always get that text "healthrelated" no matter if there's a slash in the end or not. I just need to fetch that text somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this.

```
var lastSegment = url
    .Split(new string[]{"/"}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList()
    .Last();
```

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use `Uri` class of .NET and use `segments` property:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.segments.aspx

Answer (score 0):

What you can do in this situation is either using REGEX (which I'm not an expert on, but I'm shure other ppl here are ;) ) or a simple:

```
string[] urlParts = myURL.Split('/');
```

and take the last string in this array.